# why is flush() not executing data right away? php

Tags: php, flush

I'm writing a PHP script but getting stuck on the `flush()` function. This is my script:

```
<?php
    echo "1";
    flush();
    sleep(5);
    echo "2";
?>
```

I want my script to send the '1', then wait 5 seconds, then send the '2'. But instead the script is waiting 5 seconds, then sending '12'. I'm searching for an answer for the last few hours, but I can't find one that works for me.

Comment: what are you really trying to do? sounds like you need more client side code. As it stands this is not best served by using a server-side approach

Comment: I guess you never searching on PHP manual page for flush before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use also `ob_flush()` if you use it with some sort of webserver. And `ob_flush` must always come before `flush()`.

So your code would be:

```
<?php
    echo "1";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
    echo "2";
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser.

Secondly

> It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering mechanism. This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

At the very least, try calling `ob_flush()` as well.